# NFe - ERRO no AddProt (Para quem já utilizou o NfePHP)

Tags: php, xml

**(Para quem já utilizou o NfePHP)**

Já fiz praticamente todos passos para Gerar a Nfe:

1. Criei o xml no MakeNfe
2. Assinei o xml com AssinaNfe
3. Validei com o ValidaXml
4. Enviei o Lote para Sefaz com o EnviaLote.php
5. Consultei o  Recibo com o código do recibo no ConsultaRecibo e ela foi aprovada para uso

Até aqui tudo bem, mas no *AddProt* está retornando o erro abaixo e no *TestaDanfe.php* não está encontrando o arquivo *xml*
no *AddProt* utilizando o Recibo e a Chave da *v* está acontecendo o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in /home/MEUSITE/public_html/nota-fiscal/nfephp-master/libs/Common/Dom/Dom.php on line 37

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'NFePHP\Common\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'O arquivo indicado não é um XML!' in /home/MEUSITE/public_html/nota-fiscal/nfephp-master/libs/Common/Dom/Dom.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /home/MEUSITE/public_html/nota-fiscal/nfephp-master/libs/NFe/ToolsNFe.php(349): NFePHP\Common\Dom\Dom->loadXMLString('/home/MEUSITE/...') #1 /home/MEUSITE/public_html/4.00testaAddProt.php(24): NFePHP\NFe\ToolsNFe->addProtocolo('/home/MEUSITE/...', '/home/MEUSITE/...', true) #2 {main} thrown in /home/MEUSITE/public_html/Sistema/nota-fiscal/nfephp-master/libs/Common/Dom/Dom.php on line 39
```

OBS.: Os caminhos estão corretos, não fiz nenhuma alteração nos XML só efetuei os procedimentos certos.

O que estou fazendo de errado? O que falta para gerar *NFE* e a *DANFE* em *PDF*?
Para que serve o arquivo *AddProt.php* do *NFE-PHP*?

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, passei por isso, o erro era:

tem q ser no meu caso:
$indSinc = '0'; //0=asÃ­ncrono, 1=sÃ­ncrono

para chegar o recibo pegando o arquivo gerado depois de enviar o lote